# Boost Preprocessor array element

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor

I'm refactoring some existing boilerplate code, and realised Boost:::Preprocessor could simplify things, but I've run into trouble already...  Here's a simple example:

```
#define CLASSES ( 4, ( A, B, C, D ) )
#define FOWARD_CLASS( Z, N, _ ) class BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM( N, CLASSES );

BOOST_PP_REPEAT( 4, FOWARD_CLASS, _ );
```

I would expect this to expand to:

```
class A;class B;class C; class D;
```

But I actually get:

```
error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
error: expected `)' before ‘(’ token
```

Repeated four times.  Without being able to 'see' the preprocessor output, I'm really struggling to see where I'm going wrong - can anyone more experienced offer a solution?

**UPDATE**

Switching to using a sequence makes it work:

```
#define CLASSES (A)(B)(C)(D)
#define FOWARD_CLASS( R, _ , ELEM ) class ELEM;

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( FOWARD_CLASS, _, CLASSES )
```

However, I can't see a reason why the last example didn't work!

**Repeat Ppreprocessor Output**

Here's the output of the original code (with `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`):

```
class BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM( 0, ( 4, ( A, B, C, D ) ) );
class BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM( 1, ( 4, ( A, B, C, D ) ) );
class BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM( 2, ( 4, ( A, B, C, D ) ) );
class BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM( 3, ( 4, ( A, B, C, D ) ) );
```

The line breaks have been added for clarity.  Well, it's obvious why the compiler was complaining, I wonder what else I was meant to do to force the `BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM` to expand?

Comment: Your compiler should include an option to emit the preprocessor output. For example, with gcc and clang, use the `-E` option. Also, I would expect the code to expand to `class A; class B; class C; class D;;`, since there is an additional `;` after the `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`. Are you including the necessary headers?

Comment: Also, your code [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d86d061f6729a7221b49445756cf2657-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f). What compiler and version of boost are you using?

Comment: @Mankarse Old ones, g++ v4.1.2 and Boost 1.33.1.

Comment: @cmmannett85: What is the output of `g++ -E -I/path/to/boost main.cpp -o main.ii`? It may contain clues as to why the code is not working. (I suspect a bug in the old version of boost)

Comment: @Mankarse Added, it's definitely broken!